# How do I concatenate 4 elements?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to show address in one line. How do I do this?
**My code is only showing this:**

```
<nc:StreetFullText>607 Main St W</nc:StreetFullText>
```

I know I need to add 'City', 'State', 'Zip' to the end of my line of code `AssociatedValue[@type='Street1']/Text` but I am not sure how to do it.

**Desired output**

```
<nc:StreetFullText>607 Main St W, New York, DC 77777</nc:StreetFullText>
```

**My xml**

```
      <EnumerationValue code="DC042015J">
    <AssociatedValue type="Street1">
      <Text>607 Main St W</Text>
    </AssociatedValue>
    <AssociatedValue type="City">
      <Text>New York</Text>
    </AssociatedValue>
    <AssociatedValue type="State">
      <Text>MN</Text>
    </AssociatedValue>
    <AssociatedValue type="Zip">
      <Text>77777</Text>
    </AssociatedValue>
  </EnumerationValue>
  <EnumerationValue code="DC046015J">
```

**Xslt code**

```
<nc:StreetFullText>
    <xsl:variable name="vCourtORI">
        <xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Case/Court/CourtNCIC"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\Schemas\CourtXML\SimpleTypes\CourtLocationTextType.xml'))/SimpleTypeCompanion/EnumerationValue[@code=$vCourtORI]/AssociatedValue[@type='Street1']/Text"/>
</nc:StreetFullText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a variable to select all the `AssociatedValue` elements in your document

```
<xsl:variable name="values" 
              select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\Schemas\CourtXML\SimpleTypes\CourtLocationTextType.xml'))/SimpleTypeCompanion/EnumerationValue[@code=$vCourtORI]/AssociatedValue" />
```

Then you can get the street, and the rest of the address simply by doing this:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="concat($values[@type='Street1']/Text, ', ', $values[@type='City']/Text, ', ', $values[@type='State']/Text, ' ', $values[@type='Zip']/Text)"/>
```

Alternatively, you write out separate statements to display the address, rather than try and do it in one line

```
<xsl:value-of select="$values[@type='Street1']/Text"/>
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$values[@type='City']/Text"/>
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$values[@type='State']/Text"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$values[@type='Zip']/Text"/>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. I did not think about it this way. It's working now as shown here `<nc:StreetFullText>607 Main St W, Marshall, MN 56258</nc:StreetFullText>`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do an `xsl:apply-templates` to the matching `EnumerationValue` (it looks like there are multiple) and do the `xsl:value-of` in a separate template.

If you need to handle different `EnumerationValue` elements differently, you can use a mode. In the example below I use the `sft` mode for handling `StreetFullText` specifically.

(I'm also not using namespaces or `document()` to keep the example simple.)

**XML Input**

```
<SimpleTypeCompanion>
    <EnumerationValue code="DC042015J">
        <AssociatedValue type="Street1">
            <Text>607 Main St W</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
        <AssociatedValue type="City">
            <Text>New York</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
        <AssociatedValue type="State">
            <Text>MN</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
        <AssociatedValue type="Zip">
            <Text>77777</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
    </EnumerationValue>    
</SimpleTypeCompanion>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vCourtORI" select="'DC042015J'"/> 
        <StreetFullText>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/SimpleTypeCompanion/EnumerationValue[@code=$vCourtORI]" mode="sft"/>
        </StreetFullText>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EnumerationValue" mode="sft">
        <xsl:value-of select="*[not(@type='Zip')]/Text" separator=", "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',*[@type='Zip']/Text)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<StreetFullText>607 Main St W, New York, MN 77777</StreetFullText>
```

I used XSLT 2.0 in my example because you didn't specify what version. If you're using XSLT 1.0, you can replace the `xsl:value-of` with the `separator` attribute with either:

- an `xsl:for-each`
- multiple `xsl:value-of`'s
- a single `xsl:value-of` using `concat()`
- an `xsl:apply-templates` with matching overrides
- etc...

If you are using XSLT 2.0, you could also use a single `xsl:value-of` in the `EnumerationValue` template. It's a little harder to read though:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(string-join(*[not(@type='Zip')]/Text,', '),' ',*[@type='Zip']/Text)"/>
```